# Network error 1219, multiple connections with server for user with multiple usernames are not allowed

Tags: windows-10, network-shares

In Windows Explorer (Windows 10), I typed \\server. It prompted me for a username and password. I supplied the administrators credentials to access the server and see the available shares. Going to the share I needed to go, and finding the install.txt I learned that I needed to create a network mapping to the share with different credentials.

Here's the kicker, I'm not allowed to create a new connection with different credentials because there is a phantom connection still present.

I executed a `net use * /delete` to delete every single mapping, but if I go to \\server\share in explorer, it immediately connects without asking me for a username\password. Similarly, I cannot perform a net use with different credentials.

I know that a reboot will fix the issue, but I am connected with TeamViewer and I fear that I will not be able to get back into the pc. How can I get windows to forget this previous connection without a reboot?

I tried to restart explorer, but that did not do it either.

Comment: Can you use IP for the second connection?

Comment: @HelpingHand Sure, that will work, but that's not what I want the solution to be.

Comment: I already checked credential Mananger, but the credentials were not there because I did not set the checkbox "Remember credentials". I know about the DNS tricks, but in this case I really want to know how to make windows forget without reboot or logout.

Comment: I found and checked the script I was thinking about and it uses something like `net use \\servername\sharename "%password%" /user:<domain>\%uName%` without using a drive letter. I then use to the `net use X:\ \\server\share` without having to put in credentials again. But in this case, the first credential has access to all subsequent shares and I do not need to use a different username so it's not the same. I do recall this issue though but it looks like I never found a solution & just utilized the workarounds using IP or different DNS names, etc. I'm interested in a solution to this too tho.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT Yeah, I used a similar solution today, but I want to know the solution which is why I asked the question in the first place. I indeed just tested the net use with different DNS to ensure that my script worked, but manually made a mapping. I do like your workaround though. Very elegant. Can you post that as a workaround solution, so I can mark that as answer in a few days in case no one else posts the right answer?

Comment: Oh, almost forgot to tell you, now after running `net use * /delete` and then just waiting a minute or so, I cannot reproduce the problem. I'm not sure if I was just not waiting long enough after running `net use * /delete` or what. Can you confirm if you wait say 3-4 minutes after running `net use * /delete` whether it prevents the mapping with a different user account using the `net use \\servername\sharename "%password%" /user:<domain>\%uName%` syntax? I'm not sure if I'm doing it differently than you, but suddenly using that works so I think that may be a solution? Let me know your result

Comment: Here's some correlated PS & reg locations https://pastebin.com/650c6ScF I found that I'm not sure if deleting from did anything or not for the full UNC path to the drive share. It appears the `net use * /delete` command works whether I map using File Explorer or `net use` commands with or without a drive letter. Reg keys replace ``\`` with `#` so I did remove some `##server#share` keys and such & some of the MRULists from those other paths. But when I tested it works without deleting so that may just be a coincidence. Try to wait, otherwise look over some of those paths & test some if you can.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT I had tested the `net use * /delete` option, it gave me the message: "Nothing changed because no credentials were found.

Comment: What's the winver build and edition of the Windows 10 you are using that has this problem? It is Windows 10 1909 Enterprise or something different? I want to see if I can emulate your environment exactly. The net use tells me that on subsequent runs after the first when it disconnects too, but if I keep trying to go to `\\server\share` at first after deleting credentials it works but a couple minutes later it prompts and I'm able to map to the same server and same or different share using a different credential. I have had this problem you are talking about though just need to reproduce it.

Comment: Windows 10 Pro x64 v1909

Comment: Chip - I'm using 1903 Windows 10 from what I confirmed, I will update it to 1909 soon and see if that make any difference. Mainly work with Enterprise editions in corporate environment but 1909 Pro from a Home PC coming soon. Did you by change post over that pastebin link with the text and look over those Reg paths I have commented out in that PowerShell logic from that link to the text logic or whatever? I know I removed some mount points and rebooted and I think I cleared the network drive too, assuming I'd see what comes back after reboot, but none ever came back after that and net commands

Comment: I haven't, because in the meanwhile the pc was rebooted and the problem vanished then. I currently have no computer to recreate the problem on though, but given that I manage a lot of computers for a lot of clients, I keep my eyes peeled for when I get a similar situation and do my testing then. I really do appreciate your effort though, @PimpJuiceIT.

Comment: I'm very experienced with Powershell, but fail to understand your second comment. Unless you were referring to that pastebin thingy, then yes, I understood I need to change <Username>  to whatever I am using. :)